# Authenticate users from more than two tables in laravel 8 api

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-8

As I know Auth::attempt is used to authenticate users from users table, but i want to authenticate another users from students table and teachers from teachers table. How to create multiple authentication for different users? I'm new in laravel api's

Comment: Don't. If your `Students` and `Teachers` have information unique to their type, create models to represent that but store basic, shared information in the `Users` table along with a relationship column (or columns) which identify if a `User` is also a `Student` and/or a `Teacher`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's much stuff on the net, but may this could be useful for you:
I've written medium [article](https://medium.com/@boolfalse/laravel-multi-auth-using-different-tables-part-3-admin-permissions-f78c9abc7a5b) about that, (also there's attached [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=paFXbjXgd0g&list=PL8gDJhl8MloV0_q1nQ0LViK-u3jiVQBZL&index=3) and working [repo](https://github.com/boolfalse/laravel-multiauth)).

Please be patient, I just did that 2 years ago for Laravel 5.*, but the main thing is the same for version 8 as well.